# How do you determine the strandedness of a RNAseq dataset?

Tags: rna-seq, fastq

How do you verify if a RNAseq dataset is unstranded, stranded or revesely stranded from a fastq file?

Comment: I was looking for a method that didn't involve quasi-mapping but I think this will solve my problem. Thank you!

Comment: Unless the metadata is recorded somewhere you won’t get around mapping: the FASTQs themselves don’t record this information anywhere.